# Transparent nested X server (Xephyr)

Tags: 20.04, xorg, xserver

I am using [Xephyr](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr/) to create nested X server on Ubuntu 20.04. When I execute `Xephyr :10` i have got black window. I would like to get transparent window (Xephyr's root window) to make it invisible, so it will feel like main X server. I know that it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395179/empty-or-transparent-window-with-xlib-showing-border-lines-only) and I tried to download [source code](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xserver-xephyr) of Xephyr and change window creation process to support 32-bit depth and alpha channel, but the code is really complex and seems to has hardcoded maximum depth (24-bit), so it's not the matter of changing few lines. So basic ways to change background (like `feh` or `xsetroot`) are not going to work too.

Has anyone already tried to get transparent Xephyr window or can recomment another nested X server that supports alpha channel by default?

Thanks for help

Comment: Setting a wallpaper works after starting a windowmanager (tested with openbox,bspwm,9wm and fvwm as windowmanager and nitrogen for setting a wallpaper)

Comment: Yes, but setting transparent wallpaper on 24-bit depth Xephyr will produce black background, not transparent.